# Interface to hold XML and hardcoded configuration data

Tags: c#, xml

I want to create a singleton factory that stores some data. Part of the data comes from XML file and a part of it is hardcoded.
I was suggested of defining an interface `IMyConfigData` that contains the data and having my class implement it.

1. Is this a good design? What is the advantage of defining and implementing an interface as opposed to including the data directly in the class?
2. I would like to make the below singleton thread-safe while accessing class properties? how do I achieve this?
3. There were two fields in `IMyConfigData` namely `EntityIdSite` and `EntityIdApplication`. I have combined these two into a class called `EntityId` that contains `Site` and `Application`. Does combining the elements in this way affect serialization from XML?

Interface:

```
public class EntityId
{
    ushort Site { get; set; }
    ushort Application { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyConfigData
{
  //ushort EntityIdSite { get; set; }
  //ushort EntityIdApplication { get; set; }

  EntityId entityId {get; set;}

  ushort ETypeCountry { get; set; }

  byte ETypeCategory { get; set; }

  byte ETypeSubCategory { get; set; }

  UInt32 PortNumber { get; set; }
}
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://test.com/MyConfiguration">
  <Settings>
    <setting owner="MySServer" name="AllowEditOnAreas" value="0"/>
    <Setting owner="MySServer" name="ApplicationId" value="10"/>
    <Setting owner="MyServer" name="Port" value="3000"/>
  </Settings>
</Configuration>
```

Implementation:

```
public sealed class Singleton : IMyConfigData
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance 
    {
        get { 
            return lazy.Value; 
        } 

    }
    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Singleton - a class has only one instance and provide a global point of access to it.

Here is my answer:

1) Since your class will have only one instance, there is no need to declare it as Interface. Moreover your class has properties does not have any methods.

2) To make it thread safe to support multithread application use lock to check synchronization

```
private static object syncLock = new object();

    lock (syncLock)
    {
      if (_instance == null)
      {
        _instance = new Singleton();//class to be initialized once
      }
    }
```

3) Does combining the elements in this way affect serialization from XML?
This should will not have major impact in serialization. If EntityId is not used anywhere else then better to move back those properties to main class.

Here is the complete sample.

```
public class MyConfigData
{
    ushort EntityIdSite { get; set; }

    ushort EntityIdApplication { get; set; }

    ushort ETypeCountry { get; set; }

    byte ETypeCategory { get; set; }

    byte ETypeSubCategory { get; set; }

    public UInt32 PortNumber { get; set; }

    private static MyConfigData _instance;

    // Lock synchronization object
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    protected MyConfigData()
    {
    }

    public static MyConfigData GetInstance()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new MyConfigData();
                }
            }
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Get the reference of this class using static method shown below. Expose the property as public whichever is required to be accessed outside the class. For example in this case I declared PortNumber as public.

```
MyConfigData configData = MyConfigData.GetInstance();
var port = configData.PortNumber;
```

Comment: I am using a delegate here to construct the singleton. How do I use the lock in that instance. You are suggesting moving `EntityId` to `IMyConfigData` and declaring `IMyConfigData` as a class (instead of `Interface`)

Comment: I'm not sure about delegate how you are accessing it. I have updated my answer with complete implementation. My recommendation would be to move EntityId to IMyConfigData and declare IMyConfigData as a class, if at all there is no other place where EntityId is referred.